# What is the difference between definitions and theorems?

Tags: coq

In [the current version of the Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html#lab33), the relevant explanation is formulated with intentional leeway.

> First, we've used the keyword `Theorem` instead of `Example`.
>      This difference is **mostly** a matter of style; the keywords
>      `Example` and `Theorem` (and a few others, including `Lemma`,
>      `Fact`, and `Remark`) mean **pretty much** the same thing to Coq.

*(I put the wording used to introduce uncertainty in bold.)*

In [an earlier version of, evidently, the same writing](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos510/sf/Basics.html), it was put strongly:

> The form of this theorem and proof are almost exactly the same as the examples above: the only differences are that we've added the quantifier `∀ n:nat` and that we've used the keyword `Theorem` instead of `Example`. Indeed, the latter difference is **purely** a matter of style; the keywords `Example` and `Theorem` (and a few others, including `Lemma`, `Fact`, and `Remark`) mean **exactly** the same thing to Coq.

*(I put words introducing strength in bold.)*

Looking at [the official documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html), all of these words, and more, belong to the same grammatical category *«assertion keyword»*:

```
assertion_keyword  ::=  Theorem | Lemma
                        Remark | Fact
                        Corollary | Property | Proposition
                        Definition | Example
```

There are further two sections explaining how these keywords work: [*«Definitions»*](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#definitions) and [*«Assertions and proofs»*](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#assertions-and-proofs). In short:

> Definitions extend the environment with associations of names to terms.

— And:

> An assertion states a proposition (or a type) of which the proof (or an inhabitant of the type) is interactively built using tactics.

But, as far as I see, a theorem also extends the environment, and an example can be built with tactics. So, I am not seeing where these things are different. But the Software Foundation is a clever book. If they chose to be uncertain, there must be a reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today the differences are minimal, and could be summarized as:

- `Theorem/Example/Definition/...` do produce different entries in the documentation; this is the most relevant difference.
- Some forms such as `Theorem` don't support the syntactical form `Theorem foo := nat.` for non-interactive mode, which is supported by `Definition` for example.

Another non-trivial difference is whether you use the interactive mode or not. That is to say:

```
Definition foo : Type := nat.
```

and

```
Definition foo : Type. Proof. apply nat. Qed.
```

will take slightly different code paths due to the second creating an interactive proof; the codepath when the definition gets sent to the kernel is a bit different, but Coq 8.12 should unify them for all practical purposes, just marking the second proof as opaque.

Answer (score 2):

One difference I've seen is that `Definition`s can give an immediate definition, whereas `Lemma` and `Theorem` can't.

```
Definition one := 1.

Lemma two := 2. (* syntax error *)
Theorem three := 3. (* syntax error *)
```

Out of the rest, only `Example` works.

```
Remark four := 4. (* syntax error *)
Fact five := 5. (* syntax error *)
Corollary six := 6. (* syntax error *)
Property seven := 7. (* syntax error *)
Proposition eight := 8. (* syntax error *)
Example nine := 9. (* works! *)
```